# Python ternary if on numpy array with condition on array cell values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a conditional function, say `f(x)`, that takes domain values from a numpy.ndarray `the_array` and maps into another numpy.ndarray, `result`

```
f(x) =  g(x) if x>0
    h(x) otherwise
```

`g(x)` and `h(x)` here are some other functions.

Looks to me something like the following, but I don't know how to refer to the corresponding array entries in the ternary if:

```
result = g(the_array) if <??> else h(the_array)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no problem valuating `g(x)` and `h(x)` for all of `x`, then

```
result = np.where( x>0, g(x), h(x))
```

If `g` can be evaluated only at `x>0`, we have to do more work.  For example:

```
mask = x>0
result = h(x)
result[mask] = g(x[mask])
```

Some `ufunc` take `where` and `out` parameters that work like this.  If `g` is a `ufunc`:

```
g(x, where=x>0, out = h(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = the_array
for i in range(len(the_array)):
    result[i] = g(the_array[i]) if the_array[i] > 0 else h(the_array[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this array based operation assuming your `g` and `h` function can accept all values as input (meaning `g` does not through error/exception for non-positive values and `h` for positive values). The equation is quite self explanatory of the if statement in question:

```
result = g(x)*(x>0) + h(x)*(x<=0)
```

And if your `g` function only accepts positives and `h` function only accepts non-positives, you can mask array `x` and do operations and merge them like this:

```
idx_p = np.argwhere(x>0)
idx_np = np.argwhere(x<=0)
result = np.zeros_like(x)
result[idx_p] = g(x[x>0].reshape(-1, 1))
result[idx_np] = h(x[x<=0].reshape(-1, 1))
```

example code:

```
x = np.array([-1,1,-2,2])
def g(x):
  return x**2
def h(x):
  return x
result = g(x)*(x>0) + h(x)*(x<=0)
```

output:

```
[-1  1 -2  4]
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your function is quick to evaluate, you can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html?highlight=where#numpy.where):

```
import numpy as np

def g(x):
    return x * 2

def h(x):
    return x * 10

x = np.arange(-5, 5)

result = np.where(x > 0, g(x), h(x))
```

After this, `result` is

```
array([-50, -40, -30, -20, -10,   0,   2,   4,   6,   8])
```